# Browser compatibility jQuery UI dialog

Tags: jquery-ui

I have a jQuery Dialog box on one of my pages.  One of the buttons in the dialog boxes triggers a JavaScript prompt OnClick.  Everything seems OK with the lastest versions of Internet Explorer, Chrome, and Mozilla Firefox, but some users are reporting weird behavior.

Are there any known browser compatibility errors with jQuery UI dialog boxes?

Comment: What do you mean by the latest version of IE? Have you tested on IE6?

Comment: I've tested with IE8, might there be an issue with IE6?

Answer (score 0):

There is a known issue with ui dialog and IE6, you can read more here:
http://old.nabble.com/UI-dialog-content-in-IE6-shifted-left-td18567076s27240.html

It seems that the content randomly shifts left.